# CryptographyDeprecationWarning when using docker-compose up remotely on macOSX

Tags: docker, ssh

I have set DOCKER_HOST to point to my remote server in DigitalOcean. Docker-compose works as expected but now without throwing the warnings below. Can't seem to find recent info on what to do to avoid it.

if it matters ssh versions:

```
Mac: 
ssh -V is OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d 
Server: 
openssh-client/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3 amd64 
openssh-server/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3 amd64 
openssl/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

The warnings:

```
 /var/folders/cs/p9w4g5196tl_fq7v791pwpf40000gn/T/_MEIjUWDyU/paramiko/ecdsakey.py:164: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.6p1)
/var/folders/cs/p9w4g5196tl_fq7v791pwpf40000gn/T/_MEIjUWDyU/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
/var/folders/cs/p9w4g5196tl_fq7v791pwpf40000gn/T/_MEIjUWDyU/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:96: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
/var/folders/cs/p9w4g5196tl_fq7v791pwpf40000gn/T/_MEIjUWDyU/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:111: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
```